# How to make a form for add and edit with Reack-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to create a single form able to manage the creation of a product but also to edit it (by passing the values through an object).

The form works perfectly to create a product but how to make it able to edit a product?

I tried to pass my values via "value" or "defaultValue" but it seems to be a problem with the creation of a product (The values are as saved)
The idea of creating a second form with default values passed in doesn't seem right

All this to create a basic CRUD.

Here is my form, I use Material-UI for the form elements, especially for its modal

```js
    export default function App() {
  // ReactHookForm
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();


  
  const [Produits, setProduits] = useState([]);

  
  const [openAjout, setOpenAjout] = useState(false);
  const [openModif, setOpenModif] = useState({open: false, produit: null});
  const [openSuppr, setOpenSuppr] = useState({open: false, produitId: null});

  // Load product.
  const Chargement = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${ENDPOINT}/api/produits`);
    const data = await res.json();
    setProduits(data);
  };

  // create new product.
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const re = await axios.post(`${ENDPOINT}/api/produits`, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    setProduits([...Produits, data])
  };

  // edit product.
  const onSubmitUpdate = async (data) => {
    console.log('data', data)
    // const re = await axios.put(`${ENDPOINT}/api/produits/${data}`, data, {
    //   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    // })
  };

  // delete product.
  const confirmSuppr = async (data) => {
    setOpenSuppr({open: false, produitId: data});
    const re = await axios.delete(`${ENDPOINT}/api/produits/${data}`, data, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    setProduits(prevState => {
      prevState.filter(Produits => {
        return Produits.pro_id !== data;
      })
    });
  }

  // -- Handler open / close Dialogs
  // Handlers des Dialogs
  const handleAjout = (Bool) => {
    setOpenAjout(Bool);
  };

  const handleModif = (Bool, Produit) => {
    setOpenModif({open: Bool, produit: Produit});
  };

  const handleSuppr = (Bool, ProduitID) => {
    setOpenSuppr({open: Bool, produitId: ProduitID});
  };


  // Rendering
  useEffect(() => {
    Chargement();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow style={{ background: "#cad2c5" }}>
              <TableCell align="center">{"ID"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{"Nom"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{"Description"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{"Instruction"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{"Prix"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{"Action"}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {Produits?.map((produit) => (
              <TableRow key={`PRO_${produit.pro_id}`}>
                <TableCell align="center">{produit.pro_id}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{produit.pro_nom}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{produit.pro_description}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{produit.pro_instruction}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{produit.pro_prix}{' €'}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">
                  <Tooltip title="Modifier" placement="top">
                    <IconButton
                      style={{
                        background: "#ffca3a",
                        color: "white",
                        borderRadius: "10%",
                      }}
                      onClick={() => handleModif(true, produit)}
                    >
                      <EditIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <Tooltip title="Supprimer" placement="top">
                    <IconButton
                      style={{
                        background: "#ff595e",
                        color: "white",
                        borderRadius: "10%",
                      }}
                      onClick={() => handleSuppr(true, produit.pro_id)}
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>

      <Grid>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          endIcon={<AddIcon />}
          onClick={() => handleAjout(true)}
        >
          {"Ajouter"}
        </Button>

        {/**
         * Dialog add product
         */}
        <Dialog open={openAjout} onClose={() => handleAjout(false)}>
          <DialogTitle>{"Ajout d'un produit"}</DialogTitle>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <DialogContent>
              <TextField
                type={"text"}
                name="pro_nom"
                {...register("pro_nom", { required: true })}
                label="Nom"
                placeholder="Hamburger"
                autoFocus
                variant="outlined"
              />
              {errors.pro_nom && <span>Champ requis.</span>}

              <TextField
                type={"text"}
                name="pro_description"
                {...register("pro_description", { required: true })}
                label="Description"
                placeholder="Description du produit"
                variant="outlined"
              />
              {errors.pro_description && <span>Champ requis.</span>}

              <TextField
                type={"text"}
                name="pro_instruction"
                {...register("pro_instruction")}
                label="Instruction"
                placeholder="Instruction particulière"
                variant="outlined"
              />

              <TextField
                type={"number"}
                name="pro_prix"
                {...register("pro_prix", { required: true, min: 0,  valueAsNumber: true })}
                label="Prix"
                placeholder="Obligatoire"
                variant="outlined"
              />
              {errors.pro_prix && <span>Champ requis.</span>}
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button type="reset">{"Effacer"}</Button>
              <Button onClick={() => handleAjout(false)}>{"Fermer"}</Button>
              <Button type="submit">{"Confirmer"}</Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </form>
        </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a usefule function in react-hook-form called `reset`. It allows you to predefine the values for the form. [Click here to see the documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset).

You just need to call it inside the useEffect hook and specify the fields.
But before that you need to specify a state to check if it is an "add" or "edit" action.

```
const [action, setAction] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  if(action == "edit"){
    reset({
      pro_description: "pro_description",
      pro_instruction: "pro_instruction"
    })
  }else if(action == "add"){
    reset({
      pro_description: "",
      pro_instruction: ""
    })
  }
  
}, [reset, action])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look this way. Since i'm new to React-hook-form, I take every tips you have :)